# GitHub Actions: Take Docker Tag from Angular package.json

Tags: angular, docker, github-actions

I want to build and push two docker images via GitHub Actions. First will be the `latest` tag which is all good. But the second I want to take the value from the root `package.json`'s `version` key.

How can I do so?

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.1.0"
}
```

Relevant workflow:

```yaml
      - name: Image
        run: docker build . --file Dockerfile

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_REPO }}:latest
```

So I want two docker builds to happen and pushed:

```
my-app:latest
my-app:1.1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract `version` from `package.json` using `jq` in a previous step and set it to an env var like this (assuming you're using a Linux runner with `shell: bash`):

```yaml
- name: Extract version and set it to TAG env var
  run: |
    echo "TAG=$(jq -r '.version' package.json)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

and, then:

```yaml
- name: Build and push
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
  with:
    push: true
    tags: |
      ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_REPO }}:latest
      ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_REPO }}:${{ env.TAG }}
```

Comment: Thanks worked beautifully :)